# Timed action optimization

Tags: java

I wanted to make a program task for each transaction of the system to reserve 15 minutes waiting. If exceed more than 15minutes, the program will change the state/status. If status changed within 15minutes, end the task. Is there any more better code that i could apply? such as Wait/Sleep function, is there any side effect?

```
     Date myTime       = new Date();
     Calendar cal      = Calendar.getInstance();

     cal.setTime(myTime);
     cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

     Date endTime      = cal.getTime();
     Date startTime    = new Date();

 do {


     startTime = new Date() ;

     if(checkStatus(_ID) == true )
     {
         System.out.println("Closing task");
         con.close();  // end the task
         System.exit(0); 
     }

 }while (endTime.after(startTime)) ;

// if over 15minutes, code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact solution you're looking for, but maybe it gives you an idea about how you can use the wait/notify methods.

```
public class Runner {
    static Object monitor = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        Date endTime = cal.getTime();

        long fifteenMinutes = 900000;
        monitor.wait(fifteenMinutes); // waits to be notified, max 15 mins

        if (new Date().after(endTime)) {
            // time ran out without a status change
        }

        System.out.println("Closing task");
        con.close();  // end the task
        System.exit(0); 
    }

    public void updateStatus() {
        // some status logic here
        monitor.notify(); // wakes up the monitor that is waiting
    }
}
```

Comment: I am opening my database connection to get the status. Does that mean, i will get to know result after 15min?

Comment: Some other thread would have to call the `updateStatus()` method. In that case, the thread waiting will "wake up" immediately once notify() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Only problem I see is that your code is doing a kind of busy wait. Your program's thread is busy with the loop all the time.

You could add some interval of time each loop that will give up the cpu for that interval.

Add Thread.sleep(1000) to wait for a second inside the loop.

Thread.sleep(1000) will give up cpu for 1000 milliseconds, so you could:

```
do {


     startTime = new Date() ;

     if(checkStatus(_ID) == true )
     {
         System.out.println("Closing task");
         con.close();  // end the task
         System.exit(0); 
     }
     Thread.sleep(1000); //give up cpu for the following 1 second and 'do nothing' in this time

 }while (endTime.after(startTime)) ;
```

Comment: Indeed that I also realized that my code is busying because it doing looping and also checking status. That's why i posting here looking for suggestion. I am not familiar with Sleep/Wait function, hence would like to seek for better solution

Comment: If using Thread.sleep function. For example sleep 1minutes each loop, while I having the database connection open. will it failed the connection and go wired ?

Comment: It might be problematic to keep a connection busy for so long, so you might want to get a connection every time you need it and not just once and wait for a minute between connection usages. But most db connection managers support some kind of keep alive. You can usually configure it in your connections string to the db.